# Monoid (Ring object) in a derived category

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative noetherian ring, the derived category $D(R)$ has a monoidal structure given by derived tensor product.

What are monoids and commutative monoids in this category? Are they related to $A_\infty$ and $E_\infty$ algebras?

Comment: They are analogous to homotopy associative H-spaces, and have less structure than what is necessary to get something $A_{\infty}$ etc. For that you need the stable $\infty$-category, not the derived category.

Comment: What exactly is the definition of the $\infty$-category that I need here? Any references?